# How to fill html form and scrape from a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize, scrapy

I am working on a school project.I want to build a Andriod app but before this I want to scrape some data from `220.225.101.27/MPLogin/eSewa/VehicleSearch.aspx` and have to save in my database. When you enter this site you will have to fill the vehicle registration number then it will show all the details about the vehicles.I don't need full details but I just need the owner's name.I want to get this details for all the combination of vehicle registration number.

I did some googling a found out some python library.

1. BeautifulSoup
2. Scrapy
3. Mechanize

I am new to python. Please ignore If i mixed some terminology.I just wanted to know that :

1. Which libary should I use? Which is best?
2. What should I know about filling html form and then getting details through python?
3. To do all this work successfully what should I know first?
4. What python modules I need to use?
5. How can I save this data in my database or some kind of Excel file?
6. The site is in .net will it cause any problem?

I have read the documentation of Beautifulsoup and by using this I have successfully printed the googlenews title text. But this was basic. Filling the html form and then getting the details is difficult.

I know this is long Question but i want to learn this stuff by myself.It would be very nice If somebody can guide me step by step.

Answer (score 12):

Since you haven't provided any code and you are basically asking for an advice, I'll just give you my insight.

All of the facts you've mentioned exactly point to [scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's a very powerful tool for web-scraping.

Basically, you should do the following steps to implement your task:

- go through scrapy tutorials: [here](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and [here](http://newcoder.io/scrape/)
- read about [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) language
- explore your browser developer tools, like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (or for chrome: ctrl+shift+j)
- read about using [Request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) and [FormRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest)
- go through docs on scrapy [Items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)
- read about storing scrapped data: [Exporters](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html) and [Pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Speaking about parsing this web-site specifically, it has a basic html form that can be programmatically submitted by scrapy's `FormRequest` or `FormRequest.from_response`. Then you can use a pipeline to store scrapped data in the database, or csv, or whatever.

Come back and ask if you'll have any specific (fits for q/a) question.

Hope that helps you to get started.

Comment: thanxx okay.I am going to learn and try all this stuff.

Comment: One more question..will I be able to extract all the data as I mentioned above by using the steps you said?

Comment: Scrapy should do it. Ask a more specific question in a separate thread if you'll have problems.

Answer (score 3):

It depends a bit on your exact requirements. If you do not need any data from the form page, you can simply skip this stage and directly POST your request. If you only need to scrape a few interactions, a complete screen scraping library can be somewhat daunting to learn. You could simply use an http library. It is easier to learn and you stay closer to HTTP and HTML, which may be what your teachers intended you to learn.

E.g. using the `requests` library:

```
>>> import requests
>>> payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://yourposturl", data=payload)
>>> print r.text
```

Assuming you know html, you should be able to extract the yourposturl and variables from the html of the form page.

You can then use regular expressions to extract the data from the resulting html page. This is not recommended for a general scraping solution, but for extracting data from a single page, it is usually fine.

Comment: Just came to know about Requests.I use it                      import requests
payload = {'Registration No.' : 'MP04CF6954'}
r = requests.post("http://220.225.101.27/MPLogin/eSewa/VehicleSearch.aspx, data = payload")
print r.text                                                         but i got the 404 error.Is something went wrong? I just want to print the Owner's Name.

Comment: 404 means not found. This can have multiple causes. For one, you post to the VehicleSearch page. You need to check the html from the VehicleSearch page and see what the "action" attribute is in the form that does the post. Another thing is that you may need to login first.

Comment: there is no login.Just Enter the fields's value>submit and get result.

Comment: This is a priceless answer. Back to basics and keeping it simple.